# How to get the value of a dropdown in Jquery when dom isn't rendering out a option selected attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, select, html-select, selected

Hi I have these series of options and I want to be able to pick out the value the user selects, however a `option selected` attribute is not being rendered out on any of the options in the markup? Nothing happens when I change the dropdown value either.

Is there an underlying issue here, or is there a way in Jquery to get the value the user selects with using the `option selected` attribute?

Here is my markup:

```
<select id="priceLookupDay">
    <option value="DAY">DAY</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="FormSubmit" value="Look Up" />
```

My Jquery so far...

```
$('#FormSubmit').click( function() {
        var selectedDate = $("#priceLookupDay").val();
        $("form").attr('action', $("form").attr('action', "?sd="+ selectedDate ));
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please post your JQuery/JavaScript code, as bug lies in it. Not in HTML. Also how do you call function (JS code)? Is it `onchange`  or `onclick`?

Comment: @divy3993 Ok, thank you. Please see updated post.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wyzfmn2e/) what you want?

Comment: @divy3993 Thank you very much I have not got it working with this.

Comment: OK, Glad that it worked for you. Wait posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct but you have mixed single quotes, double quotes when setting the `form`'s `attr` property.

See if this works for you:

```js
$('#FormSubmit').click(function() {
  var selectedDate = $("#priceLookupDay").val();

  $("form").attr('action', $("form").attr("action") + "?sd=" + selectedDate);
  
  alert($("form").attr('action'));

  //$("form").submit();      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="initURL">
  <select id="priceLookupDay">
    <option value="DAY">DAY</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
  </select>

  <input type="button" id="FormSubmit" value="Look Up" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry meant go not good in that last comment, but have now got it working. Thank you ever so much for your help. You don't know how long I have been looking at this!!! @ochi

Comment: Care to share your answer for everyone else's benefit?

Answer (score 0):

Using `onchange`

**HTML**

```
<select id="priceLookupDay" onchange="lookup()">
    <option value="DAY">DAY</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function lookup()
{
    var selectedDate = $("#priceLookupDay").val();
    alert(selectedDate);
}
```

[JSFiddle : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wyzfmn2e/)